# List all living nodes / actions / animations in a Cocos2D app

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Is it possible to list all living nodes (actions and animations are of interest to me too) in a Cocos2D app?

Currently I am fighting memory issues in an app and even though profiler helps with that I would like to try other approaches too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recursively list all child nodes. The start node will be your scene. For actions, I know that you can get number of actions for given node, but i don't know if it is possible to list all actions in some way.

Also, you may use CCTextureCache to check if all of unused textures were already removed from memory. It has no public methods to access this data, but you can see loaded textures names in debugger or add some dumping method.

To prevent memory leak by scheduling some action on node, that you want to remove from parent, send `cleanup` message to all of nodes before removing from parent. Or if it is instance of your class, make `[self cleanup];` in it's `onExit()` method.

I don't think, that you can receive the list of all created nodes. It sounds like garbage collection in .net =) In objective-C you must watch for leaked objects by yourself.

Comment: And what about orphaned nodes? Is it possible that a node is living in memory and some infinite action updates the node? I guess it's possible and I would like to list such nodes somehow.